# communication from web to SIEMENS LOGO

Tags: javascript, siemens

I use this code, to read a analog input, but i not have result, is give me erro in the funcion ***plc.ReadArea.***

```
**error message**
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Wrong arguments
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\jorge.vieira\Desktop\ESTUDO - LOGO\LOGO-TESTE\javascript\main.js:19:7)
    at callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks:130:17)
    --- nan:AsyncWorker ---
    at init (internal/inspector_async_hook:25:19)
    at emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks:202:43)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\jorge.vieira\Desktop\ESTUDO - LOGO\LOGO-TESTE\javascript\main.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
main.js:19
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1
**end error message**
```

The funcion plc.ConectTo its fine.

```
var snap7 = require('node-snap7');
var plc = new snap7.S7Client();

const ipAddress = '192.168.0.3';
const rack = 0;
const slot = 1;

plc.ConnectTo(ipAddress, rack, slot, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Erro:', err);
  }
  console.log('Connect ok')

  const dbNumber = 1; 
  const start = 2; //AI2
  const size = 4;
  const buffer = Buffer.alloc(size); // buffer

  plc.ReadArea(snap7.S7AreaDB, dbNumber, start, size, snap7.S7Word, buffer, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro', err);
      return
    }
  
    const value = buffer.readUInt16BE() //Read value in analog buffer
    console.log('Value analog input:', value)
  })
})
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't know any other **solutions**!

Comment: Please don't use all-caps - it's widely regarded as equivalent to shouting. Given that questions need to be in English, it would also help if you'd translate all the comments/messages into English too.

Comment: Why are you keeping the error message secret from us?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't post code images or errors if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask